# Hook error in PHP on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I am working on Wordpress theme and added a bootstrap modal to the website "Register" link. In the modal-body I copied and paste all the HTML & PHP code from the registration page (the purpose is to open a registration page as a modal and not as a new page). But when finished pasting the code I had an error of blank page for non logged in users.

I checked each line of code pasted into the modal-body section and found out that the code that is causing this problem was:

```
<?php hook_register_before(); ?>
```

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This is the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Vt8NAUJAh4

Comment: When you put `ini_set("display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, what did it say?

Comment: The page starts with <?php. Where should I put that line of code?

Comment: Well, if you have narrowed it down to the `hook_register_before();` line (presumably by removing things until the page worked?) you can put it right before the `hook_register_before();` inside the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Typically you should put it at the top of that piece of code page because it lets you know all errors/warnings that happen on that page, not just the part that is causing the fatal error you are getting.

Comment: You are right, this is how I narrowed it down. Regarding the line of code you asked me to put on the page, I'm sorry but I tried without success. Can you advise haw to do this exactly?

Comment: I tried to put it but the code indicates an errors

Comment: Indicates no errors or does indicate errors?

Comment: indicates errors on the .php page itself

Comment: What do the errors say? You need to fix what the errors are saying...

Comment: The page starts like this:
<?php

function WLT_FeedbackSystem($authorID){  global $CORE, $wpdb, $userdata;
I didn't figured out where to put the code

Comment: Then put it like so: `<?php ini_set("display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); function WLT_FeedbackSystem...etc.`

Comment: I tried and the code seem to indicates error as if you forgot to put a comma or sothing like that. Here is a link for the whole code:
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=nNmkxF9um0

Comment: Copy and past the error in your question.

Comment: The error is in the code itself and not on the webpage. Can you check it out please? https://jsfiddle.net/c1aa81zv/

Comment: Yeah, that's not helpful unfortunately. The error can not happen in the code, so I am not sure what to tell you. Sorry!!

Comment: The error happends in the code after copy and paste the line of code you asked me to put in... If i will remove this line code there were not be any errors in the code

Comment: Oh, no just paste the error up above in your question so I can read what the error says, not into your code page.

Comment: I understand my friend but i cannot put the ini code you wanted me to put in my .php file, so I am not getting any errors since the debugging if false